# Async method is getting nowhere

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await, c#-5.0

I have the following method and use it in my console application:

```
 static async Task<List<Task<CompositeType>>> callSvcAsync(List<CompositeType> listC)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IWcfServiceLayerChannel> cn = new ChannelFactory<IWcfServiceLayerChannel>("MyWcFServiceEndpoint");
        var c = cn.CreateChannel();
        List<Task<CompositeType>> listTasks = new List<Task<CompositeType>>();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
        {
            Task<CompositeType> res = c.GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(new CompositeType() { BoolValue = true, StringValue = "SomeString" });
            listTasks.Add(res);
        }

        CompositeType[] value = await Task.WhenAll(listTasks);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        listC.AddRange(value);

        **c.Dispose();**

        return listTasks;

    }
```

The code is calling a wcf method 1000 times.
A list object is populated afterwards and the time consumed by the operation is displayed in the console.
When I dispose my wcf channel nothing happens. The method does not return to the calling code.
When I comment out "\c.Dispose()" then everything works fine.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I have no answer to my question above, but the following code works:

```
async public static Task<CompositeType[]> AsyncWcfCall()
    {
        ChannelFactory<IWcfServiceLayerChannel> cn = new ChannelFactory<IWcfServiceLayerChannel>("MyWcFServiceEndpoint");
        var c = cn.CreateChannel();
        c.Open();


        List<Task<CompositeType>> listTasks = new List<Task<CompositeType>>();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
        {
            var res = c.GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(new CompositeType() { BoolValue = true, StringValue = "SomeString" });
            listTasks.Add(res);
        }

        return await Task.WhenAll(listTasks).ContinueWith((ct) =>
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            try
            {                   
                cn.Close(); c.Dispose();
            }
            catch {  }
            return ct.Result;               
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I am just playing around with C# async a bit and the following code does what I want. So the question is still not answered, but this works:

Comment: No, it hasn't, but the the concrete channel has ootb a dispose method. And it won't fire an exception, cause disposing the concrete channel instance has nothing to do with the channelfactory instance.
...just testing C# async with WCF calls...that's the intent.

Comment: Actually, I don't need the ContinueWith after whenall, just have to put the code, that resides inside ContinueWith into the finally block...

Comment: I have created a simple wcf service application project in VS2012. I did not changed the ootb interface. Create one and you will see how the interface looks like:

Client proxy generated using:
svcutil http://xxx/WcfServiceLayer.svc

c is of type:
IWcfServiceLayerChannel{System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}

Comment: Yes, I have renamed it, but the implementation is the same.
As mentioned before, I generate the proxy using svcutil and it creates a cs file:

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IWcfServiceLayerChannel : IWcfServiceLayer, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

IClientChannel implements IDisposable, therefore I can call Dispose() directly on the object.

public interface IClientChannel : IContextChannel, IChannel, .., IDisposable
    {
But why is it going nowhere (or deadlock, don't know) when I call dispose

Comment: I am sorry, my bad - I completely forgot about the _helper_ channel interface the proxy generates as i've always been working with original contract interface with `ChannelFactory`. Nevertheless, I am unable to reproduce any deadlock from your first code snippet - it works fine for me.